# Не могу понять, пишет код ошибки 02

Tags: c++

Код, в котором ошибка:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    for (t = 1; t < 100; t++) {
        if (t == 57) break;
        cout << t << ' ';
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return;
}
```

Comment: надо текст сюда скопировать, а не ССЫЛКУ на КАРТИНКУ! А во вторых где именно ошибка? в какой строке? а вы `return` для функции возвращающей `int` как должны делать?ъ\

Comment: я пытался вставить код, но сайт по кд выдавал, что я не так его оформил

Comment: Функция `main` у вас описана как возвращающая `int`. И это верно. Но **что** она возвращает?

Answer (score 0):

Функцию `main` должна возвращать число а не пустоту, поэтому место `return` напишите `return 0`

Comment: Вписал, теперь выдает ошибку и завершается кодом 0

Comment: @anubislive "Доктор, у меня что-то болит" - "Ну, выпейте каких-то лекарств"... Вы бы почитали хоть пару страниц сайта, а главное - это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Прошу прощения за свою некомпетентность, свои ошибки исправлю и в дальнейшем такого не повторится.

Comment: @anubislive  что за ошибку то выдает?